# All IntelliJ run configurations disappeared

Tags: intellij-idea

After IntelliJ IDEA froze and was killed from the task manager, all the Run/Debug Configurations disappeared. I have tried invalidating caches, reloading files from disk, synchronizing and restarting, but nothing helped.

Comment: Were they saved Run configurations? Or auto created by Right Clicking the Class and clicking Run?

Comment: I've had this problem more than once, as well. There's clearly an IntelliJ bug such that if the process is killed, it will wipe your Run Configs, including real saved ones, not just temporary ones.

Comment: and months after the bug is still here. All the changes lost, local history empty, just because my Virtual Machine crashed with PyCharm open on it. Is there no way to recover them?

Comment: This happens to me occasionally with random configuration sets, and without any crashes nor any apparent changes to the local history. I've opened [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-164719) on IntelliJ's issue tracker.

Comment: @diegopau 

Please see my answer - looks like no more problem

Comment: @Eyal Roth   Please see my answer - looks like no more problem

Comment: @Patrick Please see my answer - looks like no more problem

Comment: @Arashsoft Please see my answer - looks like no more problem

Comment: I'm sorry for the spam, but only one recipient can be notified in one comment( 

Please, consider this comment like feature request at stackoverflow site family - do let to notify multiple recipients in a comment!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can try to restore your Run configuration using the **Local History** feature of IntelliJ IDEA.

If you are using `.idea` directory based format, then your configurations will reside in `workspace.xml` file under `.idea` directory, invoke **Local History** dialog from the **.idea** directory right click menu in IDEA **Project View**, select the label some time before the crash and revert the old copy of `workspace.xml`.

In case `.ipr` file based format is used, your configurations will be stored in the `<project>.iws` file in the project root which you can restore in a similar way.

If the configurations were **Shared**, they are stored in `.idea\runConfigurations` directory as separate XML files or in the `<project>.ipr` file (if old project format is used).

If the **Local history** is blank and you are in Windows, try **Restore previous versions** right clicking the `workspace.xml` file or the `<project>.iws` one in **Windows Explorer**.

Comment: Thanks! restoring the **.iws** file from the Local History did the trick. Before reading you're answer I thought the the **.ipr** file stores the run config (and restoring it didn't helped)

Comment: What if the local history is blank?

Comment: Apparently this doesn't always work. As KickingLettuce indicated, some users cannot access local history for workspace.xml (or respective files) - same problem for me. Is there any other solution? Probably best to create a backup of the file at a moment where it is working ...

Comment: I think IntelliJ is using workspace.xml at my project. The problem was that it was filled with binary data after the crash and there was no local history available.

Comment: Does this solution require having **.idea** folder in the same folder of the project? I don't, so I don't see **.idea** folder in **Project View**. Is it still possible to recover the configurations, how?

Comment: how can i configure it so that in the future workspace.xml will be part of LocalHistory? in  my project I have 2 files that don't have LocalHistory available, interestingly they are colored a different color (olive in darcula)

Comment: You may need to click on the drop-down menu in the Project View and change the view to "Project Files" in order to see the .idea directory

Comment: @ycomp, I have the same issue, workspace.xml does not have "local history". Any solution for it?

Comment: I have a .ipr file based format used for my project. As mentioned above by other users, even for me services.iws does not have an option of Local history. Is there any way around this? Also, in my case, Intellij did not stop ungracefully, rather I closed all processes properly and ran a build before reopening IDE.

Comment: I  had similar issue where none of my debug configuration were being loaded after restart. I fixed this, by renaming the corrupt workspace.xml to workspace.old and restarting the IDE. Once restarted it recreated workspace.xml and configuration started saving correctly.

Comment: Thank you @Ellipsis I had a quick upgrade to 2018 EAP from which I came back to 2017.3, as it lost my run configurations. Your workaround lost me some other configurations but got me back the run configurations.

Comment: @Ellipsis - I don't know when my run configurations stopped appearing in the run option. Its probably after upgrading from intellij 2017 to 2018. I removed the old workspace.xml file and inteliij created a new one for me. But, I still have the same problem, i.e. run option does not show any configurations. Any idea how I can fix this ?

Comment: If you are in Windows, try "Restore previous versions" right clicking the `` `workspace.xml` file in Windows Explorer. It worked for me and Local History didn't

Answer (score 9):

You can go to your main project and right click on it, select local history --> show history. Find some point in time where you think that system was stable (before crash) and click revert. This worked for me.

Comment: This is very similar to the answer crazyCoder wrote, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 8):

To me, this frequently happened on switching branches. Turning off "restore workspace on branch switching" helps to prevent the run configurations from getting lost.

**Edit:** Not sure if it actually has an impact, it still seems to happen to me sometimes, maybe less frequently though. I'll leave it here since the answer already has some upvotes, so maybe this was the solution for someone...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i've accidentally pressed `Alt + Home` and this bar disappeared, this combination toggles run bar at the top of IDEA window for me.

Here the screen with my bound actions on this keys. I hope it should help
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For every project in intellij there's a file created with all the configurations related to it.
Under the root directory of the project there's a hidden folder .idea in it is the **workspace.xml** with the configuration. **workspace.xml** is comprised of components one of which is responsible to hold the run/debug configurations.

If this file is getting corrupted it's difficult to restore these configurations if you don't have a backup of workspace.xml. to overcome it:
**1.** in intellij right click the **workspace.xml** file under project view and choose Local History -> Show History
**2.** if there's no history you can copy the component from a coworker with similar configurations.
**3.** backup in advance the **workspace.xml** and retrieve the **RunManager** component from it..

another good choice is to use the share option.
under each project's definition there's a checkbox **share**

Marking this checkbox will extract the definition for this project to an external location:
under the same .idea folder a new folder is being created **runConfigurations** and the configurations per project are being represented there in xml files.

The advantage of using share is that it can be copied and used for similar projects under other branched like QA and production

Comment: thank you very much, this thing helped me alot

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me recently and I just restarted IntelliJ and they shared ones (in `.run`) are now restored.

Answer (score 1):

In my case what happened was I did something that made IntelliJ recognize the project as a new application type, so it thought my old configuration was not valid for my project anymore and wasn't displaying it to me. I reverted my changes and the configuration appeared as an option again.

Answer (score 0):

Run configurations are stored in your project files. When IntelliJ (or your computer with IntelliJ running) crashes hard, the project files can become corrupted and unreadable. I don't know of a way to recover this unless you have your project files are backed up somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your project folder and check weather any .idea folder is created or not,
if created copy your project and paste it other location ant try opening it;
it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have the problem that all the run/debug configurations are not created from CMake after being lost. I solved this by just deleting the whone list of configurations from the workspace.xml (from .idea folder).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this feature can't be removed from IntelliJ but I guess this can help:

Run/Debug configuration functionality might be hidden, so to show it go to:
View/Appearance/Navigation Bar

Answer (score 0):

I get this when I switch branches, the Run configurations are still there, if you go and edit one of them they will magically re-appear.

Answer (score -1):

Very annoying problem in Intellij Idea for many years.

It's quite often breaks because of broken (connection to?) Ant debugger, used to create run configs.

I was periodically searching for a solution, but no success. Then today after disappeared Run Config to display in panel I did inspect contents of workspace.xml. All the run configs were there.

And then it turns out to be 7+ years [bug](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206842755-Run-configurations-is-broken) clue...
Always spring out non-called Ant...

Happily, contents of ***workspace.xml*** in place with all your run config items, you can just

- disable infamous plugin Ant debugger,
- reload the project,

and all your run configs are displayed and available again))).

Happy to share with all of you the solution).